# SQL Server 2008 not working by using LIMIT keyword

Tags: sql-server-2008

This query is MySql

```
select
   a.id,
   a.name,
   a.vehicle,
   a.amt,
   a.date
   (select id 
    from tbl1
    where date < a.date and vehicle = a.vehicle
    LIMIT 0,1) as prv
FROM
   root_tbl a
WHERE
   amt <> 0
```

I need this query in SQL Server. Could you please assist me.

Comment: `LIMIT` is a non-ANSI standard compliant, custom extension used in MySQL - it's not present in SQL Server. You need to use `SELECT TOP (n) .....`

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` is not supported by SQL Server.

If you want to get the first x rows of a table, you have to use `TOP`, as in `SELECT TOP (10) * FROM tbl1`.

To do an offset equivalent, there are a few techniques, such as a subquery adding `ROW_NUMBER()` to the result set, and in the parent query filtering by for the desired offset.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum   
    FROM tbl1
    ) T
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 51 AND 75 -- Similar to LIMIT 50,25
```

For your specific query, you seem to just need a TOP to be most efficient, so the following should work for your query.

```
select
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.vehicle,
    a.amt,
    a.date
    (select top (1) id from tbl1 where date < a.date and vehicle=a.vehicle)as prv
FROM tbl1 a
```